# Flushing WordPress permalinks using a hook

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm creating a panel with custom options for my theme, and one of the capabilities I'm adding is it to change a Google Maps location pin icon for users that use the Divi theme.

It's basically an on/off button, where "on" mode should add the following code to htaccess:

```
function my_htaccess_contents( $rules )
{
$my_content = <<<EOD
\n # BEGIN Changing Marker For Divi Users
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/images/marker.png$ somepath/marker.png [L] 
</IfModule>
# END Changing Marker For Divi Users\n
EOD;
    return $my_content . $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_htaccess_contents');
```

It works fine, but after switching the option to ON, before it can take effect, I must go to Permalinks option and click the save button - how can I make it so permalinks are rewritten automatically within the need to save them?

I did some googling and tried adding the following:

```
...
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_htaccess_contents');
flush_rewrite_rules( $hard ); //nothing happens

...
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_htaccess_contents');
flush_rewrite_rules(); //nothing happens

...
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'my_htaccess_contents');
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true); //breaking page (I get 500)
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?
Also, is there a way to remove the added content when the option is turned off in my panel?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some ajax functions to regenerate permalinks automatically after you turned on the settings in the theme panel.